# How can I print out something when I have KeyError for my dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, exception, keyerror

So I have a code for my dictionary:

```
def get_rooms_for(dict1, num):
    try:
        for x in dict1:
            if x == num:
                print(dict1[x])
    except KeyError:
        print (num,"is not available.")
```

And my test is

```
get_rooms_for({'CS101':3004, 'CS102':4501, 'CS103':6755,'NT110':1244, 'CM241':1411}, 'CS999')
```

And I expect my result is to print out 'num' parameter with string saying

```
CS999 is not available.
```

But when I put it this it returns empty 
What should i have to do if I want to pick an KeyError in dictionary, using exception code??

Comment: Just try by  removing `for` and `if` then only `print(dict1[num])` inside that `try` block.

Comment: Can't we use .`get` method here?. `dict1.get(x, "%s is not available." % x)`

Answer (score 2):

When you enter the `try` loop you're then looping over all the keys in the dictionary. `CS999` isn't a key in the dictionary, so you never try to access it. Thus you never hit a `KeyError`, and the `except` clause is never reached.

What you want to do is more like this:

```
def get_rooms_for(dict1, num):

    if num in dict1:
        print(dict1[num])
    else:
        print("{} is not available".format(num))
```

But Python already has a method for that: `get`

```
dict1.get(num, "{} is not available".format(num))
```

Which will return the value mapped to `num` if it's in the dictionary, and `"{} is not available".format(num)` if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
def get_rooms_for(dict1, num):
    try:
        for x in dict1:
            if dict1[num] == x:
                print "It will print particular key's {0} value if its exists or It will generate keyerror".format(dict1[num])
            print(dict1[x])
    except KeyError:
        print (num,"is not available.")
```

Output :

```
('CS999', 'is not available.')
```

Comment: If `KeyError` is there why we have to use `for` loop and `If` ?

Comment: This code is terrible. The loop is pointless, the `"It will generate keyerror"` print can only execute in cases where there is no KeyError (and cannot execute at all for dicts structured the way the question's example dict is structured), it's printing every value instead of the value for `num`, etc.

Comment: @user2357112 i added the loop in a function just because user might want to do some action by accesssing `num` in that `dict1`

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
def get_rooms_for(dict1, num):
    try:
       print(dict1[num])
    except KeyError:
       print (num,"is not available.")
```

Comment: if that key not present it will throw `KeyError` . That I'am catching below and prints my own error message .

Comment: @GarbageCollector: What the heck are you talking about? No part of this code is going to go over all the dict's values, and the error message is only printed if it hits a KeyError.

Comment: Eh, the code is okay, but the answer would be a lot better with an actual explanation instead of just a "try this" code dump.

Answer (score -2):

You also can try without `try` and `exception` :

```
def get_rooms_for(dict1, num):
    if dict1.has_key(str(num)): # or str(num) in dict1
            print "Key available"
    else:
        print num,"is not available."

get_rooms_for({'CS101':3004, 'CS102':4501, 'CS103':6755,'NT110':1244, 'CM241':1411}, 'CS999')
```

output:

```
CS999 is not available.
```

Comment: `has_key` is deprecated in Python 2 and removed in Python 3, and the `str` call is pointless.

Comment: so we can use `in` keyword in that case.

Comment: @downvoter : please explain the reason. Batman gave same answer and got 2 upvotes.

Comment: Well, for one thing, Batman gave a completely different answer, with none of the problems I mentioned, and an additional solution using `get`.

Comment: @user2357112 : ok.. great :)